How to find which docker version that added support for COPY --link?
NOTE: This is both a question of WHICH docker version, and also HOW to find the docker version, that implemented COPY --link.
Background: It started with my local docker install not supporting COPY --link when parsing my Dockerfile. After a quick search I see it was added to the Dockerfile frontend version 1.4.0 [1].
After that I got stuck. I have no idea how to find what version of docker that implemented Dockerfile frontend version 1.4.0. But some luck searching I found a page mentioning that COPY --link was added in Docker Engine 26.0 [2][3].
And some extra luck took me to the list of milestones for Docker Engine 26.0 [4] which lists a pull request named "Dockerfile: update xx to v1.4.0" [5].
At this point I still do not know what docker version that got support for COPY --link. I have not found how to map Docker Engine version to a docker release.
Edit: ignore this part. apt show list available packages, not installed packages. I do not have docker verison 24.0.5.
apt show docker.io on my machine show that I am using docker version 24.0.5 (24.0.5-0ubuntu1~20.04.1).
But docker version show both client and engine having version 19.03.13.
So where does version 24.0.5 come from? Edit: ignore this part.
The docker software landscape feels like a convoluted mess that I fail to make sense of. It also seems to be split between the two repos https://github.com/docker and https://github.com/moby .
So back to the question: How are you supposed to find which docker version in Ubuntu that implemented support for COPY --link?
[1] https://github.com/docker/docs/blob/c416e68959110bb8d04d92de3f9f0d3e181360b1/content/build/dockerfile/release-notes.md#140
[2] https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/how-to-accelerate-docker-builds-and-optimize-caching-with-copy-link/
[3] https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/26.0/#2600
[4] https://github.com/moby/moby/issues?q=is%3Aclosed+milestone%3A26.0.0
[5] https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/47570

The feature was added  in buildkit PR #2596.
That was then released in Dockerfile v1.4.0 (this is the frontend parser used by buildkit to interpret your Dockerfile).
From there you can use the #syntax=docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1.4.0 line at the top of the Dockerfile to pull in that feature. Or, to avoid the dependency on the #syntax line, you can wait for it to become the default Dockerfile frontend parser.
The Dockerfile frontend was updated to 1.4.0 in buildkit v0.10.0.
And the first docker engine release with that version of buildkit is 23.0.
That said, in my experience, this feature was more trouble than I gained from it, so I quickly removed it from my own Dockerfiles. I believe it would result in issues like unpredictable parent directory permissions.

Permission problems seems to have gotten a workaround, according to the tracking issue posted in @harrymc answer. Workaround seems to have been included in docker 23.0.2.

As far as I could track the problem, I found this bug-report
COPY --link does not rebase cached layers on top of changed layers #1099.
A comment by
polarathene
said:

In March a point release of Docker Engine (23.0.2) intentionally
disabled the COPY --link
support it
seems. The release notes reference a Github PR for that
change, this related
BuildKit PR notes that there is some extra work Docker Engine
specifically needs to handle before they enable COPY --link again.
Subscribe to this tracking
issue to know when it is
resolved for Docker Engine.

Therefore the problem is with version 23 only. Versions 22 and 24
might perhaps work.
A later
comment by mahangu
said:

COPY --link will work with the default docker
driver on Docker CE 24
beta and later, as long as containerd
storage is enabled.

However, reading the linked tracking issue
mergeop/diffop not working properly with Moby worker #45111
doesn't seem very optimistic as regarding version 24, written
on Dec 22, 2023.
You'll have to try and see, perhaps trying out the latest beta version.

I listed the wrong docker version by mistake. I have corrected my question.
Docker version is 19.03.13.

Note that the current version is 26.0.1.
